# angularjs html5 hash url

Tags: angularjs, google-api, angularjs-routing

I am using server side google oauth in angular.js,

Suppose my redirect url is localhost:8000/redirect. To remove # in angularjs I am using

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

But, when i visit the url I get an error :

```
Error response

Error code 404.

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.
```

However if I type the url manually i.e `localhost:8000/#redirect` then I  get what I expected and then redirects to localhost:8000/redirect

I have also tried to add # from Google app console. But, that is not allowed.

So how to remove hash completely ?

Comment: what are you using for server side??

Comment: On server side you shall return layout html file in any case, something like this in nodejs: `app.get('*', function(req, res){ res.sendfile('/views/layout.html'); })`

Comment: I am using angularjs partials , and partials are working perfectly with "#"